# Jquery how to make on click or on change with element with id ends with string

Tags: jquery, click

I want to make something like this:

```
  $('.select').on("click", $( "checkbox[id$='select-all']" ), toggle);
```

Basically i want to run toggle function only if checkbox with select-all suffix in id is clicked inside element with .selecte class. But toggle function is run on every checkbox clic. What i'm doing wrong here? The same is for on chenge event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$('.select').on("click", "input[id$='select-all']", toggle);
```

The [`.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) lets you (optionally) specify a selector as a string in the second argument. It's not expecting a jQuery object, and if you *do* pass an object it assumes it is data that will then be passed to the event handler as `event.data`.

Also I assume your checkbox is actually an input with `type="checkbox"`, so your selector string needs to be `"input..."` not `"checkbox..."`. (Or you could use the [`:checkbox` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) but I think that is likely less efficient. Perhaps `"input:checkbox[id$='select-all']"`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $('.select').on("click", "checkbox[id$='select-all']", toggle);
```